# Not setting correct scrollPosition on navigation

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3

When I navigate back in my application, I want the page to keep the same scroll position as before.
If I scroll to the bottom of the page, click a link and go back again to the main page, the page is not scrolled all the way to the bottom.

The page has a long list of elements, and it seems the scroll position is being set before all the elements have finished rendering.

Current config

```
// app/router.options.ts
import type { RouterConfig } from '@nuxt/schema'

export default <RouterConfig>{
    scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        console.log("to", to)
        console.log("savedPosition", savedPosition)

        if (savedPosition) {
            return savedPosition
        }
        return { top: 0 }
    }
}
```